# What do I do with the FLG pin on the static mic3975

Tags: circuit-design

I'm messing with using the mic3975-1.8ymm (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic3975.pdf) The problem I'm having is I'm not sure what to do with the FLG pin's output if I'm not going to monitor it.

Do I do the pull-up, then send it to ground? Can I leave it floating (my reading of the doc says "no")?

I've spent most of the day trying to find an answer, but all I have found is about what to do with unused input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Flag (Output): Open-collector error flag output. Active low = output under-
>   voltage.

It's an output, and open collector, if you don't need the output you can leave it unconnected, or even ground it if that makes layout easier.

this is borne out further by the functional diagram on page 8

Answer (score 2):

**Pull it up** to the VOUT using a pullup resistor. The value of the pullup can be  10k\$\Omega\$.
[image]
[image]

---

Comment: for proper operation of what?

Comment: @Jasen of the system if a MCU is connected to it for example.. I believe.. so you are right .. 99.99% the OP can leave it open.

Comment: It seems to me the pull up is only needed for the proper operation of the flg output

Comment: Thank you both. I tagged Jasen as the answer, but voted both of you up. The comments were vary helpful!